Fine-tuning argument and stochastic independence
I don’t understand the fine-tuning argument for the existence of God. People argue that if the laws of physics (in particular, certain constants of nature) were even slightly different, elementary particles wouldn’t be able to come together to form atoms, and nothing interesting would ever happen in our universe. They claim that it’s just too much of a coincidence for these constants to be precisely what they are, so a creator must have set them intentionally.
(Underlying this argument is the assumption that we can assign a specific probability distribution to the possible values of these natural constants. While I would contest this assumption, I will accept it for the sake of argument.)
Now, while I can grant that under the assumption above, the probability of these constants falling into the precise range required for life is exceedingly small, this argument overlooks the fact that our ability to observe this phenomenon is not stochastically independent from the phenomenon itself. The probability of the constants being in this range, given that we are able to make the observation, is 1. If the constants were different, we wouldn’t exist to make the observation in the first place. In other words:
• P(laws of physics are such that life can form) = „very small number“

• P(laws of physics are such that life can form | humans exist and make this observation) = 1.0

For this reason, I fail to see how the fine-tuning argument provides any evidence for the existence of God.

I don’t have this problem with the Fermi paradox. We can observe multiple planets and check if they contain life, we can’t, however, observe different universes, and compare their laws of physics.

This  isn't a question; it's an argument.

This just seems to be stating the anthropic principle without asking any question.  Vote to close.

This question might as well ask “What do fine-tuning proponents react with to the anthropic principle”, since that’s pretty much what’s implied here.

"I don’t understand the fine-tuning argument for the existence of God." Yet you did a pretty good job summarizing it...  It seems you meant to say that you don't agree with it, yes? That's OK, people examine the same set of facts and come to different conclusions all the time.  We can all do better to accept this fact about human nature.  Do you have an actual question though?

Well, I’m not a philosophy student, but I’ve encountered this argument often in some debates on religion (latest in the debate panel with the Archbishop of Canterbury and Alex O’Connor). And they portrayed this argument as one of the biggest problems that atheists can’t explain, and I’ve just never heard someone mention the points in my question as a response. So I was wondering what people that studied philosophy think about the fine-tuning argument, and its flaws.

The Anthropic Principle only explains why there is life in our type of universe, it does not explain why our type of universe exists.  The full non-theistic response to the fine tuning argument is that there are an infinity of universes, and yes most of them are remarkably uninteresting, but a very few will be able to create complex chemistry and exist for long enough for life to develop via abiogenesis.  And every intelligent life that then tries to understand its universe will be misled by apparent fine tuning, which is actually just the Anthropic Principle.  But a multiverse is needed.

As the Wikipedia article on fine tuning notes, cosmologists agree the Fine Tuning Argument is strong, and as a result basically every non-theist cosmologist has adopted a Multiverse framework in response to the apparent fine tuning evidence.  Note we have no evidence whatsoever for a multiverse, so this is a pretty complex and unsupported guess needed to explain Apparent Fine Tuning.  A good book articulating this idea is Leonard Suskind's The Cosmic Landscape.  I review it here:  https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-reviews/R3JVQDAK1408BR?ref=pf_ov_at_pdctrvw_srp

Congratulations, you have discovered the anthropic principle.
Version 1 of the argument: Considering any possible Universe in which life can exist (or any possible Universe at all), the life that exists within must almost-certainly observe that the Universal constants/physical laws appear fine-tuned to its existence because, cosmologically, life is so fragile. Thus, assuming that the Universe came about in some life-forming fashion, it is almost impossible for any life form not to observe the Universe to be fine-tuned for its existence. Note that nothing here implies the design of the Universe to suit any given life form.

Version 2 of the argument, possibly more common: we can take the existence of humanity as a given (just the same as we take the existence of the CMBR, of other stars, of mutated fish, etc. etc. etc. in any scientific logic) since it is unequivocally, certainly, surely the case. Then, knowing that human life requires very specific universal constants and physics to come about, we infer that some mechanism (or random chance) caused those exact constants and physics to come about. Note that the fact that we do not understand that mechanism, or if there was a specific mechanism at all, does not imply that it was a result of design.

Another argument on the subject that I particularly like: suppose the Universe’s constants were random (unlikely, but what fine-tuning proponents suggest) and that only a very very small fraction of initial states would allow for human life. It isn’t actually special that the cosmic dice landed on humanity’s side. Suppose a simpler example: I roll twenty d20s, and I get the numbers 1, 2, 3, …, 18, 19, 20, in order. The probability of this occurring randomly is on the order of 10^-26, but not zero.
Just because it is improbable does not mean that its occurrence implies that the dice were loaded or that I cheated somehow or that a god designed the situation; it is simply the occurrence of an improbable event. The Universe is the same way, with bigger numbers and dice with more sides.

With the anthropic principle and related logic in mind the fine-tuning argument falls apart, you’re right. But belief/disbelief in God is hardly something we should be trying to convince each other about anyway.

Thank you, I agree with everything you say:) So is it the case that this argument from fine-tuning isn’t considered valid among “philosophers of religion”? I’m not a philosophy student, so I’ve only encountered it while watching debates online and so on.

It is sometimes taken that fine-tuning is evidence for god - there are counterarguments to anthropic principles that are considered valid by some (not by me, but that’s a matter of opinion) - but if purified logic is what you’re looking for, the occurrence of an improbable event doesn’t imply anything about a designer.

What do you mean by "purified logic"?

As in, unless you want to bring in unreasonable assumptions (like that all sufficiently-improbable events must be designed). There is no actual logical connection, without any such assumptions, that would lead a logician to the conclusion that because an improbable event occurred there must be a designer.

This is a special pleading fallacy.  All empiricism operates by asking "why is the world like it is" and accepting the answers that provide an explanation, even though in every case there is a non-zero chance the world "just happened to be that way".  You are repeating the rationalist rejection of empiricism, and if you adopt it with fine tuning, then to be consistent you need to adopt it with all the rest of empiricism too.  @HenryT.

@Dcleve Why is there necessarily a reason that the Universe should be one way or another? Why is "there is physics that we don't know yet that explains it all" not rational, and why is "barring worse explanations, we just rolled the d10^100 and got a 1" not rational (see also stochastic quantum mechanics not having any apparent reason for anything), and why would the explanation "a designer was involved" be rational when we have zero evidence for that claim except for the problem itself, making the design explanation just beg the question?

No physics explanation will ever pass your criteria for “explanation”.  Every such explanation has an infinity of other possible explanations per Quine-Duhem. Science and empiricism do not use your criteria rationalist proof criteria, nor absolute truth.  They instead use pragmatic truth, and Inference to Best Explanation based on a set of judgement calls about competing explanations.  Rationalist rejection of most useful/powerful inferences because they might be wrong applies to every empirical process, and would prevent your getting up this morning. @HenryT.

(Why a designer is at all any more implied than random chance, I don’t know.)

Teleology.  An otherwise inexplicable coincidence, such as finding a watch in the woods, or a city’s foundations on an uninhabited island, or an apparent message in stellar radio noise, can be explained by assuming a reasonable design intention and designers created the otherwise inexplicable event.  In each case one could also assume a wild set of coincidences.  Science operates by treating explanatory theories as vastly preferred over low probability random events. @HenryT.

In all of those cases, there are actual mechanisms through which that design can take place. An errant watchmaker can perfectly-well build a watch; a sufficiently-large group of pranksters can set up a fake city anywhere; a sufficiently-large civilization can broadcast radio messages. There is no known physical mechanism through which the physical constants could be altered at all, let alone fine-tuned, especially in a way so precise and with such foreknowledge to guarantee a particular civilization's creation. You necessarily speak of a god - omniscient, omnipotent - which is unphysical.

The physical constants are exactly that - constants - and they interplay in an extremely complicated way. You cannot design a Universe to produce a specific civilization ~13.8 billion years later without almost-perfect foreknowledge of all that would occur beforehand, which is impossible without being capable of almost-perfectly predicting quantum wavefunction collapses that occur constantly throughout the Universe (especially in its early life when forces were still separating). Needless to say there is therefore not a physical mechanism through which a designer could design a Universe.

(Note also: if I were to wipe the Universe clean and start over from exactly the same initial conditions, there is no reason to expect I would even get the same Universe again, due to that stochasticity. You cannot design that which you cannot actually control.)
